# Unit test for MVC 5 async Task<ActionResult> Index view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to unit testing. Not sure what to do my testing on, I went ahead and started one with an Index view on ClientController. I am having issues writing test method for the Index view which is declared as async Task. What i want to do is make sure this action returns data. Not sure how important this test is but I wanted to learn ways to write tests in MVC 5. Seems to have trouble writing tests for the view that are async.

ManagementService class

```
public IQueryable<Client> GetAllClients(bool includeDeleted = false)
    {
        var query = context.Clients.AsQueryable();
        if (!includeDeleted) query = query.Where(c => !c.IsDeleted);
        return query;
    }
```

Client Controller

```
public ClientController(IApplicationContext appContext, IManagementService adminService, IDomainService domainService)
    {
        this.adminService = adminService;
        this.appContext = appContext;
        this.domainService = domainService;
    }
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var clients = adminService.GetAllClients();
        return View(await clients.ToListAsync());
    }
```

//TEST

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Index()
    {
        //Arrange
        var mgmtmockContext = new Mock<IManagementService>();
        List<Client> db = new List<Client>();
        db.Add(new Client { ClientId = 1, Name = "Test Client 1" });
        db.Add(new Client { ClientId = 2, Name = "Test Client 2" });
        mgmtmockContext
            .Setup(m => m.GetAllClients(false))
            .Returns(() => { return db.AsQueryable(); });

        //Act
        ClientController controller = new ClientController(null, mgmtmockContext.Object, null);

        var result = controller.Index() as Task<ActionResult>;

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

After I create an instance of the controller, I am not sure how to pass the mock object to Index() so I can test this view returns data.

What I want to Assert is Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Count()) so I can run this test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out. Testing async wasn't easy. Got the MockingHelper class from asp.net.

```
public static class MockingHelper
{
    public static Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> AsMockDbSet<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> data)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<TEntity>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity>(data.Provider));
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());
        mockSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator()).Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<TEntity>(data.GetEnumerator()));
        return mockSet;
    }

    public static Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> AsMockDbSet<TEntity>(this IEnumerable<TEntity> data)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        return data.AsQueryable().AsMockDbSet();
    }
}
```

And AsyncTestingClasses too.

```
internal class TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity> : IDbAsyncQueryProvider
{
    private readonly IQueryProvider _inner;

    internal TestDbAsyncQueryProvider(IQueryProvider inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        return new TestDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>(expression);
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new TestDbAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(expression);
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        return _inner.Execute(expression);
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        return _inner.Execute<TResult>(expression);
    }

    public Task<object> ExecuteAsync(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Execute(expression));
    }

    public Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Execute<TResult>(expression));
    }
}

internal class TestDbAsyncEnumerable<T> : EnumerableQuery<T>, IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T>
{
    public TestDbAsyncEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
        : base(enumerable)
    { }

    public TestDbAsyncEnumerable(Expression expression)
        : base(expression)
    { }

    public IDbAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator()
    {
        return new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T>(this.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator());
    }

    IDbAsyncEnumerator IDbAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator()
    {
        return GetAsyncEnumerator();
    }

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
    {
        get { return new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<T>(this); }
    }
}

internal class TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T> : IDbAsyncEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> _inner;

    public TestDbAsyncEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _inner.Dispose();
    }

    public Task<bool> MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_inner.MoveNext());
    }

    public T Current
    {
        get { return _inner.Current; }
    }

    object IDbAsyncEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }
}
```

Then changed my TestMethod as below.

```
public void Default_Index_Returns_Data()
    {
        //Arrange
        var appmockContext = new Mock<IApplicationContext>();
        var mgmtmockContext = new Mock<IManagementService>();
        var domainmockContext = new Mock<IDomainService>();
        var agency1 = new Agency() { Name = "Test Agency" };
        List<Client> db = new List<Client>();

        db.Add(new Client { ClientId = 1, Name = "Test Client 1", AgencyId = 1 });
        db.Add(new Client { ClientId = 2, Name = "Test Client 2", AgencyId = 1 });

        //Act
        mgmtmockContext
            .Setup(m => m.GetAllClients(It.IsAny<bool>()))
            .Returns(() => { return db.AsMockDbSet().Object; });
        ClientController controller = new ClientController(appmockContext.Object, mgmtmockContext.Object, domainmockContext.Object);

        var resultTask = controller.Index();
        resultTask.Wait();
        var result = resultTask.Result;
        var model = (List<Client>)((ViewResult)result).Model;

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, model.Count());
    }
```

This worked. Thanks Alexei and Kenneth for your help. I hope this helps everyone.

Answer (score 7):

In order to get the list out of the result you need to do two things:

1. Get the actual result from the task
2. Get the model out of the action result

Here's how you do this:

```
    var result = controller.Index() as Task<ViewResult>;

   // Get the actual result from the task
    var viewresult = result.Result;

    // Get the model from the viewresult and cast it to the correct type 
    // (notice in the first line I changed ActionResult to ViewResult to make sure we can access the model.
    var model = (List<Client>)(viewresult.Model);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, model.Count);
```

Comment: Should be `var model = (List<Client>)(viewresult.Model);`

Answer (score 5):

You can either get `controller.Index().Result` or change test to be `async`:

```
[TestMethod]
 public async Task Index()
{ 
  ....
   var result = await controller.Index();
   Assert.IsNotNull(result);
   var model = (List<Client>)((ViewResult)result).Model;
   Assert.AreEqual(2, model.Count())
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `var result = await controller.Index()`

Comment: I tried this but before I get to the model part, when i debug the code, var result is null. There is no data. Am I doing anything wrong on the mgmtContext.Setup part?

Comment: When I debug the test further, this is what the controller.Index() is returning. controller.Index()
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
Id = 1, Status = Faulted, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
    AsyncState: null
    CancellationPending: false
    CreationOptions: None
    Exception: Count = 1
    Id: 1
    Result: null
    Status: Faulted

Comment: If you get an error that looks like "Cannot await Task<ActionResult>", check that the System.Web.Mvc assembly is added to your test project.